# Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I have Checked the SQL Server Configuration Manager TCP/IP is Enabled.But Still I am Facing same issue.I have added sqljdbc4.0.jar

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Sample;" />
    <property name="username" value="someValue" />
    <property name="password" value="someValue" />
</bean>
```

Can Some Help me to solve the above issue

Comment: Make sure the server has TCP enabled *on port 1433 on all addresses or at least on address 127.0.0.1 plus ::1 on recent Windows versions*; that may or may not be the default depending on the SQLServer version and install type. To make sure it really is, do `netstat -ano |findstr :1433` and check that there is a line of output with second field (Local) `0.0.0.0:1433` or `[::1]:1433` or `127.0.0.1:1433` and `LISTENING` and the rightmost number (PID) is the processid of the(a) sqlservr.exe or similar process in TaskManager, commandline tasklist, or similar. ...

Comment: ... If/when 1433 is listening and you still get refused, as the error said it may be a firewall issue. Action then depends on what firewall you are running; recent Windows comes with a basic one builtin, but not always enabled; there are third-party ones and in particular many (most?) Antivirus or Security products include a substitute firewall, often not called firewall but a fancy name like 'Superfly Network Attack Protection'. But most firewalls will pop a dialog when a new connection is attempted and tell you how to allow it. which you would have seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Thanks all you for your response.Issue has been Resolved.Followed the below steps to allow windows firewall

1) On the Start menu, click Run, type `WF.msc`, and then click OK.

2) In the `Windows Firewall` with Advanced Security, in the left pane, right-click `Inbound Rules`, and then click New Rule in the action pane (upper right corner). In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then click Next.

3) In the `Protocol` and `Ports` dialog box, select `TCP`. Select Specific local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the Database Engine, In my case we are using the default which is `1433`. Click Next.

4) In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click Next. In the Profile dialog box, I am going to Leave Domain turned on and turn private and public off. Then click Next

5) In the Name dialog box, type `"Allow SQL 1433 Inbound”` and for a description I am putting in the same. Then click Finish -

Restart the `SQLServer(MSSQLServer)` Service  and try Again.

This will Work