# Problems connecting jdbc to MySql server on openshift

Tags: java, mysql, sql, tomcat, jdbc

So I'm using microsoft's jdbc jar in my tomcat server to connect to a Mysql server hosted on openshift.
Firstly here's the tomcat code...

```
try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                out.println(e1);
            }
            try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.x.xx.x:3306;DatabaseName=encryptionserver", "phpadminuser", "phpadminpass");
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Username FROM LoggedInUsers WHERE Username='" + user + "'");
                String u = "none";
                while(rs.next()){
                    u = rs.getString("Username");
                    out.println(u);
                }
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                out.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString() + " in getFriendRequest");
            }
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin credentials that I use to access the sql server in openshift, so perhaps that's the issue? It fails at the second try and it catches the SQLException e outputting

```
SQL Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 1xx.x.xx.x, port 3306 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.". in getFriendRequest
```

I've tried testing it by running tomcat locally, on openshift using the server ip for the DriverManager.getConnection and just using localhost as the ip. Both give back the same result.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592717/error-connection-refused-connect-verify-the-connection-properties) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed) helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incorrect jdbc driver. For MySql you must use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class provided by [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

See also:

- [Connect to MySQL with JDBC driver](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)
- [Using Connector/J with Tomcat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat.html)